# simple RxAndroid code not working

Tags: java, android, kotlin, rx-java2, rx-android

i've been trying to run this simple peace ofcode but itskeep giving an error in syntax

here is the error:
[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6HnM.png)

and here is my code :

```
    package com.moein.rx_test

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import io.reactivex.Observable
import io.reactivex.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers
import io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlatMap.subscribe
import io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers
import org.reactivestreams.Subscriber
import org.reactivestreams.Subscription


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    Observable.just("Hello World")
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            //each subscription is going to be on a new thread.
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    //observation on the main thread
    //Now our subscriber!
    .subscribe(object: Subscriber<String>(){
        override fun onComplete() {
            TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

        override fun onSubscribe(s: Subscription?) {
            TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

        override fun onError(e: Throwable?) {
            //TODO : Handle error here
        }

        override fun onNext(t: String?) {
            Log.e("Output",t);
        }
    })

}
}
```

i tried all these libraries when importing the subscribe
[libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lc8fU.png)

how can i fix this?

Comment: I think the type of your object has to be `Consumer` actually

Comment: i think Kotlin also pukes if it runs in to the TODO block if i remember correctly, you need to either implement it or remove that TODO block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Observable`'s default consumer type is `Observer`:

```
.subscribe(object: Observer<String>(){
    override fun onComplete() {
        TODO("not implemented")
    }

    override fun onSubscribe(s: Disposable?) {
        TODO("not implemented")
    }

    override fun onError(e: Throwable?) {
        //TODO : Handle error here
    }

    override fun onNext(t: String?) {
        Log.e("Output",t);
    }
})
```

Comment: That `onSubscribe` implementation will probably crash the observable before it can begin

Comment: I'm sure those were meant to be placeholders until the compilation issue was resolved.

Comment: For future reference for future readers, I think using `DisposableObserver` with `.subscribeWith` is a better choice. Although you most likely know all that :D